Define a common interface without dynamic polymorphism
In applications such as ray tracing, an entity can be one of several types, which all share a common interface. For example, a Material can either be a DiffuseMaterial or a ReflectiveMaterial, etc and they all support a method Color getColor(args); In most applications, this issue is typically resolved using dynamic polymorphism:
class Material {
public:
  virtual Color getColor() = 0;
  // ...
}
class DiffuseMaterial: public Material {
public:
  Color getColor() {
    // ...
  }
}
class ReflectiveMaterial: public Material {
public:
  Color getColor() {
    // ...
  }
}

Then, a function can use Material* to represent a material, which is either of these types.
This virtual class hierarchy not only allows the user to define a common behavior, it forces the user to define the virtual function, otherwise the programmer cannot create instances of the derived classes, because they are abstract. However, dynamic polymorphism causes a performance overhead due to the dynamic dispatch and lookup. This is a problem in high-performance programs.
More modern languages provide alternatives to dynamic polymorphism. Rust for example has traits (interfaces, which can be resolved at compile-time) and enums (the entities of which can be structs), which avoid dynamic polymorphism. For example,
enum Material {
  DiffuseMaterial{member1, member2}, // a struct
  ReflectiveMaterial {member1, member2, member3, } // a struct
}

How to achieve the same effect of dynamic polymorphism using compile-time polymorphism features in C++20? Namely, define a type, which can be one of several types. Forcing the programmer to define a custom implementation of the common behavior for each subtype would be nice, but isn't a must.

One alternative to dynamic polymorphism with virtual functions is by using std::variant :
no base class is required, no pointer to base class, no virtual functions;
"define a type, which can be one of several types" is exactly what std::variant did.
However I don't think the performance penality of virtual function is very high.

@jls28 That'd be very similar to ordinary runtime polymorphism using virtual functions but without the benefits. With classes implementing multiple interfaces, the number of combinations would soon be unmanagable. OP wants it to be resolved at compiletime

I disagree, there are benefits, no dynamic memory required, no base class, no pointer to base class.

@jls28 Just because a class has virtual functions it doesn't automatically require dynamic memory allocation even though it's common. I don't see why defining the interface in a base class and/or having a base class pointer is a bad thing when runtime polymorphism is wanted. A vtable will most probably be more effective than std::visiting a variant, especially a variant that has to cover a huge amount of interface combinations. Anyway, as I mentioned, OP wants compiletime polymorphism, so neither polymorphic classes nor std::variant are good fits.

You could create a concept that checks all the requirements that you have on a Material:
template <class T>
concept IMaterial = requires(T m) {
    // list the requirements here
    { m.getColor() } -> std::same_as<Color>;
};

The actual classes implementing the requirements can then be completely unrelated:
class DiffuseMaterial {
public:
    Color getColor() { return Color{}; }
};
class ReflectiveMaterial {
public:
    Color getColor() { return Color{}; }
};

... and you can use the concept to only accept types that fulfills the requirements.
Example:
template<IMaterial M>   // M must fulfill the requirements
class Foo : public M {  // or composition if that makes more sense
    void func() {
        Color c = this->getColor();
    }
};

Demo

This would do the trick nicely, thank you! It's simple and not ugly and convoluted. I also found this article, which provides additional help.
I wonder what was the practice before C++ concepts came into existence? Perhaps some obscure design pattern? If I remember correctly, Curiously Recurring Template Pattern could be used.

@KotakaDanski You're welcome! Before concepts one could create type traits to do similar validations. CRTP can also be of use, both prior to C++20 and after.

the solution with variant :
#include <variant>

enum Color {}; // what you wish

class DiffuseMaterial {
public:
    Color getColor() { return Color{}; }
};
class ReflectiveMaterial {
public:
    Color getColor() { return Color{}; }
};

void your_function(std::variant<DiffuseMaterial, ReflectiveMaterial> & mat)
{
 Color color = std::visit([](auto & m) {return m.getColor();}, mat);
}

int main()
{
 std::variant<DiffuseMaterial, ReflectiveMaterial> mat = DiffuseMaterial{};

  your_function(mat);
}


Thank you for this alternative. A typedef for std::variant<...> should make this even more concise. However, from what I read about std::variant, it uses dynamic dispatch for std::visit, which could reduce the possible gains. Some people claim that this can be optimized away, but it isn't always guaranteed. I guess I will have to benchmark and see which runs best. For example, for representing different kinds of rays, using an enum RayType member turned out to be faster than Ray<RayType>, even though it takes more memory in the cache.
